# How to add Multiple Google Tag Manager Containers In A Single Android App?

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I am in a situation where I need to add multiple Google Tag Manager (GTM) containers into a single android app, every GTM container is for separate client.

Found this solution but its outdated as I can't download GTM necessary file as binary as shown in the link below, I only can download it in json format.

https://www.tatvic.com/blog/quick-guide-adding-multiple-google-tag-manager-containers-single-android-app/

tried to use the json file instead of binary file, it throw an exception error.